# Why so much Dependencies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do all these dependencies in a React app not affect performance?

I am fresh to javascript development with frameworks (React to be precise).
Building a fullStack app at the moment. 
I am still working on the frontend, and package.json is already looking so populated.
I am enjoying this, but I keep thinking of the effect it could have in production.
And the node modules are excluded (.gitignore) in production, so what does the app depend on when deployed?

```
{
  "name": "smart-brain",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "clarifai": "^2.9.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-particles-js": "^2.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.2",
    "react-tilt": "^0.1.4",
    "tachyons": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't worry too much about performance until you actually have performance issues. 90% of the time, you'll just be wasting time pre-optimizing. Also, seven dependencies is really nothing.

Comment: I guess you are right Cos I saw a project with over 20. I guess I will have to do some deep theory reading, cos it all seems like magic to me

Comment: Even twenty isn't that many; it's probably average, maybe below average. There is not necessarily a direct relationship between number of dependencies and performance. If you're really concerned about performance, look at your bundle sizes and run performance tests.

Comment: Not just performance, but security. Who knows what all those packages do ?
I would hope that there is a package-minimiser program somewhere that actually prunes the tree,
I would rather start from a clean sheet and just build in what's needed.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let me start off with the statement that just because `node_modules` is listed in `.gitignore` doesn't mean it's excluded for the production environment. You will need to install the packages listed under `"dependencies"` in your `package.json` file in production (via `npm install --only=production`) before running your node app.

Also, you may see `"devDependencies"` when you install packages via `npm install -D [package name]`, and these are packages you use in development. You will normally install all the packages listed in your `package.json` file during development via `npm install`, but you will need only the packages listed under `"dependencies"` in production by running `npm install --only=production`.

Secondly, the number of packages doesn't have a direct relationship to runtime performance. It could have a small impact in your app startup time because it need to load the packages (given that you are using them in your app), but it is hardly a concern to anyone.
Also, to address your concern of the large number of dependencies, each packages are normally designed to solve one problem -- like authentication, validation, date/time manipulation, rendering, etc. -- so you may see a lot of dependencies in a typical node web app. However, the size of `node_modules` isn't too much of an issue to most node developers, but because of how big it can get, there are even memes about it. But again, it's a problem of mere storage size rather than performance.

Comment: This is very clear. "Startup time" I guess depending on the package purchased on hostings like heroku, that can be efficiently taken care of

Comment: Startup time in Node.js is negligible on any platform for most developers. I've been using Node for almost 4 years now and I hardly ever worried about the startup time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the only dependencies specified in package.json are:

```
"dependencies": {
    "clarifai": "^2.9.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-particles-js": "^2.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.2",
    "react-tilt": "^0.1.4",
    "tachyons": "^4.11.1"
  }
```

Many production apps I have seen have a good deal more dependencies than that, and build tools like webpack are quite good at optimizing performance and reducing the size of your bundled javascript code.

Also, as you noted, since the node_modules are .gitignored, they won't be tracked in git. However, depending on how you are building and deploying your app in production, there will likely be build scripts that run on the server, which will run `npm install` (among other things) and download the dependencies there.

Hope that helps a bit!

Answer (score 1):

> How do all these dependencies in a React app not affect performance?

Its not going to affect the performance if its not going to run the extra code. The extra code is going to sit there on the disk, but do nothing to the performance. But yes your `app` will be larger (files size).

> And the node modules are excluded (.gitignore) in production, so what
>   does the app depend on when deployed?

Yes it will exclude and it should exclude the `node_module` because you dont need to transfer all the packages to your server as copy and pasting. And it should not be uploaded to github either. Otherwise it will take forever to upload and download the repository. And whoever download the repository will need to run `npm install`.

Also, you will need to run `npm install` after the deployment as you will have to run `npm run`. And thats how `dependencies` section of `package.json` come in handy, to know which packages to install on the production server.

Comment: Larger file sizes still affect performance, even if never executed, because it still has to be parsed.

Comment: I am pretty sure Google and Firefox spent thousands of engineer ours to make sure that affect to performance is negligible.

Comment: Perhaps I should be clearer — it affects the initial load, not the execution. The additional code has to be downloaded and parsed before the browser could determine that it's unreachable.

Comment: Hence only startup time is affected? I guess a good hosting package will efficiently manage or reduce that

Answer (score 1):

> so what does the app depend on when deployed?

If the `"dependencies":` section is written correctly then your React app will depend on:

- all the entries, let's call it `entry1`, `entry2`, in this section. Each entry is located under `node_modules/entry1`, `node_modules/entry2` and so forth.
- the dependencies of `entry1`, `entry2`, ...  and so on located under `node_modules/entry1/node_modules`, `node_modules/entry3/node_modules` and so forth. Note `entry2` is not mentioned here, let's assume it doesn't have further dependencies.
- further dependencies down the dependency tree e.g. dependencies of the dependecies of `entry1`, ...

The dependency tree is usually optimised by a special program called 'bundler'. Webpack is a popular bundler, it bundles dependencies into a bundle which is a JS file called for example `my-bundle-1.js`. The bundle(s) are referenced in the `<script>` tag in the .html file. Which webpack can, by the way, generate along with the bundles.

You can tell webpack to put the code you write into one or more bundles and put all the dependencies found under `node_modules` in to another bundle which is commonly called 'vendor' bundle. Then you can look at the bundle sizes and compare. Note that in production build webpack can (and should) minimise bundles and compress them. This affects performance, smaller bundles load faster.

I don't think `"react-scripts": "3.1.2"` should be in the `"dependencies":` section, it's better be placed under the `"devDependencies":` section.

Comment: ooKay alright This is clearer I will look into the react scripts thing, But why do you say that?

Comment: The `react-scripts` package is used at the build time, not at the run-time.